# Irreducible representations and commutative C*Algebras.

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $A$ is a commutative C*-Algebra then also its representation $\pi(A)$ is commutative, and it's an operator C*-algebra.

A representation is said to be irreducible if $\pi(A)$ does not commute with any nontrivial projection operator.

So if $A$ is commutative in $\pi(A)$ there are no nontrivial projection operators.

Now, if $\pi$ is a representation on a Hibert space $H$ of dimension greater than one it shouldn't be irreducible, but I'm unable to prove it.
I don't see how to apply the spectral theorem, like it's suggested in the text I'm reading.

Can you give me a little help please?

Comment: If the Hilbert space has dimension greater than 1 then a non trivial projection operator does exists. That projection operator is Normal. Hence in some way I should apply the spectral theorem to that.

Answer (score 7):

It is not necessarily true that $\pi(A)$ will have non-trivial projections. But $\pi(A)''$ will, because it is a von Neumann algebra.

Now, the assertion you are looking at is basically trivial. You want to prove, for $A$ abelian, "if $\dim H\geq2$ then $\pi$ is not irreducible". This is the same as its contrapositive, which is "If $\pi$ is irreducible, then $\dim H=1$". The proof of this is like this: if $\pi$ is irreducible, then $B(H)=\pi(A)''$; then $B(H)$ is abelian, which only happens when $\dim H=1$.

To see that $B(H)$ is not abelian when $\dim H>1$, consider an orthonormal basis $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots\}$ (it doesn't have to be countable) and define two bounded linear opeartors by 
$$
Se_1=e_2,\ \ Se_j=0\ \text{ if }j\ne2;
$$
$$
Te_2=e_1,\ \ Te_j=0\ \text{ if } j\ne 1.
$$
Then $STe_1=0$, $TSe_1=Te_2=e_1$. So $TS\ne ST$.

Comment: Excuse me, it's not clear why if $\pi$ is irreducible then $B(H) = \pi(A)''$.

Comment: It's basically by definition. What's your definition of "irreducible"?

Comment: $\pi$ is irreducible if $\pi(A)$ commutes with no nontrivial projections. Now, it's clear that $cl(\pi(A)) = \pi(A)''$ because even if $\pi(A)$ is not unital, it's possible to find a strong approximate unity. I also know that $\pi(A) \subset \pi(A)'$. If $\pi$ is irreducible there are no nontrivial projections in $\pi(A)'$ (and thus neither in $\pi(A)''$). Maybe I don't see something obvious... why $\pi(A)''$ is all of $B(H)$?

Comment: Because if $\pi(A)$ commutes with no nontrivial projections, this means that $\pi(A)'=\mathbb C\,I$ (otherwise, there would be a nontrivial projection in the commutant of $\pi(A)$); then $$\pi(A)''=(\pi(A)')'=(\mathbb C\,I)'=B(H).$$

Comment: How does $B(H)=\pi(A)''$ imply that $B(H)$ is abelian? I assume it's because $\pi(A)''$ is abelian, but then I'm not sure why it is abelian. I know of a "nice" theorem which says if $A$ is an abelian $C^*$-algebra then $\pi(A)$ will be an abelian $C^*$-algebra. So is the commutant of an abelian $C^*$-algebra itself abelian?

Comment: That $\pi(A)$ is abelian if $A$ is not a theorem, it's not even an exercise: $\pi$ is a homomorphism, so $\pi(a)\pi(b)=\pi(ab)=\pi(ba)=\pi(b)\pi(a)$. The double commutant is a closure. That closure of abelian is abelian is again an easy exercise.

Comment: Right. The hard part is actually getting that $\pi(A)$ is a $C^*$-algebra. My definion of the commutant is: $\pi(A)'=\{T\in B(H):T\pi(a)=\pi(a)T \text{ for all }a\in A \}$. How does one get that if $\pi(A)$ is abelian then $\pi(A)'$ is abelian from that.

Comment: I never talked about the commutant. Only the double commutant. As I mentioned, t's a trivial consequence of the Double Commutant Theorem.

Comment: I have yet to see the Double Commutant Theorem. I do know that $\pi(A)'=\mathbb{C}I$, as you mentioned in the comments. This clearly gives (based on the definition I put in the comments) $\pi(A)''=B(H)$. But I still don't see why the double commutant is abelian.

Comment: Because $\pi(A)$ is abelian. $\pi(A)''$ is the sot-closure of $\pi(A)$.